# Get client IP NOT web server IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

```
public static string GetPublicIp()
    {
        string direction = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org");
        using (WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            direction = stream1.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //Search for the ip in the html
        int first1 = direction.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last1 = direction.LastIndexOf("</body>");
        direction = direction.Substring(first1, last1 - first1);

        return direction;
    }
```

I'm trying to get the client IP when an asp.net page loads. I have tried using the checkip.dyndns.org service as shown in code snippet above but that returns the IP of the web server hosting the ASP.NET application.

Is there away i can modify that code and have it return the Client public IP? (**I need their public IP and not their local IP**) OR is their a better example of how to return the clients public IP (NOT THE WEB SERVER IP)

Comment: Why not simply get the IP that is shown as request? That is the last public IP that your web server knows about. And easy to get - just look at the request.

Comment: If the client and server are not communicating over the internet, but instead over a private network, then you cannot determine the clients internet IP address from the server as it is simply irrelevant in the communication between the 2 parties. It is essentially their IP address on a completely different network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var userIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```